# Get Id of just created Raven Document

Tags: ravendb

Say I'm storing a new document without specifying an id so it uses the raven automatic one, how would I then retrieve that id for immediate use?

```
League league = new League(){Name = "League1"};
RaventSession.Store(league);

Division division = new Division(){ Name = "Division1",
                                    LeagueId = //need league id for this property
```

Comment: A way you can do this, in addition to the suggestion by the accepted answer, is to have an .Id property on your League object. After you call .Store it will be populated.

Comment: Yes I was previously using this method, but I wanted to avoid assigning an id myself.

Comment: To clarify, the .Id will be populated automatically for you when you call .Store.

Comment: Ah I understand, thanks Judah

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you store an entity, the id is assigned to the entity (if you don't set it) then check league.Id after `RaventSession.Store(league);`

note that you can also use `RaventSession.Advanced.GetDocumentId(league);` to retrieve the stringId of the entity

Comment: Perfect! Thanks!